# On continuously uniquely geodesic space II

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, algebraic-topology, metric-spaces, geodesic

This question was inspired by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481569/on-continuously-uniquely-geodesic-space/482242#482242) of [@wspin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/51049/wspin).

**Definition** : A continuously uniquely geodesic space is a [uniquely geodesic space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_Riemannian_and_metric_geometry#U) whose geodesics vary continuously with endpoints.

> **Question** : Is a [complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space) uniquely geodesic space, continuously uniquely geodesic ?

Comment: The answer is no (but yes if we replace complete by proper): see [here](http://www.math.bgu.ac.il/~barakw/rigidity/bh.pdf) page 38 (3.13 and 3.14)

Comment: A complete answer was already given https://math.stackexchange.com/a/654193/12434. (By the way the answer there that you accepted is not right.)

Comment: @AntonPetrunin: thanks!

Comment: As Anton pointed out, the reference mentioned in my first comment comes from GGT in the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/654193/84284) to a previous question.

Answer (score 2):

Not a complete answer, but it might be useful:

First of all one needs to clarify what "geodesics vary continuous" means. I assume this means that for converging sequences $x_n \to x$ and $y_n \to y$ the corresponding sequence of geodesics $c_n$ from $x_n$ to $y_n$ converges to the geodesic $c$ connecting $x$ and $y$, that is if we parametrize $c_n$ and $c$ proportional to arc length on the interval $[0,1]$ we find that $c_n \to c$ uniformly.

The following seems correct: Let $(X,d)$ be a uniquely geodesic space. Then $X$ is continuous if $X$ is compact (which implies that $X$ is complete):

The proof is an easy consequence of the the Arzela Ascoli theorem for compact metric spaces: For a compact metric space $X$ any sequence of curves $c_n \subset X$ with uniformly bounded length contains a uniformly converging subsequence.

Now assume $X$ is not continuous. Choose a sequence of geodesics $c_n : [0,1] \to X$ such that the endpoints converge, $c_n(0) = x_n \to x$ and $c_n(1) = y_n \to y$, but $c_n$ does not converge to $c$, the geodesic from $x$ to $y$. We claim that there exists an $\varepsilon > 0$ and a subsequence $c_{n_k}$ of $c_n$ as well as a sequence $t_k \in [0,1]$ such that $$d(c_{n_k}(t_k),c(t_k)) > \varepsilon$$
for all $k$. It is easy to proof this claim from our assumption that $c_n$ does not converge to $c$. Maybe after taking another subsequence of $c_{n_k}$ we may assume that $c_{n_k} \to \tilde c$ for $k \to \infty$ by the Arzela-Ascoli theorem. Since geodesics converge to geodesics we obtain a contradiction as $\tilde c$ is a different geodesic connecting $x$ and $y$.

Some remarks:

- I have no idea whether this remains true for only complete spaces. But conversely to my previous guess i'd say no :)
- Observing this proof it is clear that it is enough to assume that for some $x \in X$ and all $r > 0$ the closed ball $\{y | d(x,y) \leq r\}$ is compact, which is weaker than compactness of $X$.
- A complete length space (a metric space where points are connected by geodesics) is not locally compact, i.e. small balls at a point need not be compact. See for example [Complete implies locally compact in length metric space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69854/complete-implies-locally-compact-in-length-metric-space)
- A good reference for the Arzela-Ascoli thm used here is "Burago et alii: A course in metric geometry". Uniquely geodesic spaces are a special case of length spaces which are discussed there in great detail.

Comment: Thank you ! The assumption in your second remark is the locally compactness, right ? The spaces $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ or $l^{2}(\mathbb{N})$ are not locally compact, but complete and uniquely geodesic, right ? Are there continuously uniquely geodesics in your opinion ? Perhaps an other theorem in functional analysis could permit an access to a next step for this question (Rudin's book).

Comment: The assumption in my second remark is different from local compactness; you need closed balls of arbitrary size to be compact. Local compactness only ensures small ones to be compact. E.g. an open ball in euclidean space is locally compact but does not satisfy the assumption in my second remark. I'm not sure about $l^2(\mathbb N)$ but $\mathbb R^\infty$ should be not locally compact, complete and continously uniquely geodesic.

Comment: A closed ball (of arbitrary size) is a finite union of small closed balls, so if the small closed balls are compact, so are the closed balls (of arbitrary size), isn't it ?

Comment: Consider the open unit ball in $\mathbb R^2$ with the induced metric. It is locally compact but for example the closed ball of radius 2 at any point equals the whole space, which is not compact.

Comment: You're right, but the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is not complete. There is a theorem : a metric space is compact iff it's complete and totally bounded.